# Xamarin.iOS app crashes on startup with iPhone5 when downloaded from app store. DYLD, Library not loaded error.-+

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, app-store

I am working on a Xamarin application. The app works fine when deployed Ad-Hoc on my iPhone5. The App works fine on iPad and iPhone6 both in Ad-Hoc and App Store versions. However, I get an instant crash when I try to start the App Store/TestFlight version on my iPhone 5.

Here is the crash log :

```
{"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.3.4 (14G61)","build_version":"1.3.1","timestamp":"2019-11-25 14:01:05.33 -0500","app_name":"CPEEP.iOS","bundleID":"com.altilogix.cpeeps","incident_id":"CE93C272-D023-4058-AE75-6BF205893BEB","name":"CPEEP.iOS","is_first_party":false,"app_version":"1.3.1","share_with_app_devs":true,"slice_uuid":"8d939558-dc29-3773-ba5d-be06524a29ef","adam_id":1455126201}
Incident Identifier: CE93C272-D023-4058-AE75-6BF205893BEB
CrashReporter Key:   686e40dceea53078e133cbcd92ef064c6b7840a0
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
Process:             CPEEP.iOS [330]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/23B56006-7F53-468B-AAC2-18B74EA02613/CPEEP.iOS.app/CPEEP.iOS
Identifier:          com.altilogix.cpeeps
Version:             1.3.1 (1.3.1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.altilogix.cpeeps [527]


Date/Time:           2019-11-25 14:01:05.2600 -0500
Launch Time:         2019-11-25 14:01:05.0000 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.4 (14G61)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: @rpath/MaterialComponents.framework/MaterialComponents | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/23B56006-7F53-468B-AAC2-18B74EA02613/CPEEP.iOS.app/CPEEP.iOS | Reason: image not found
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x03f1c1dc 0x3efa000 + 139740
1   dyld                            0x03f1be3e 0x3efa000 + 138814
2   dyld                            0x03f1be78 0x3efa000 + 138872
3   dyld                            0x03efdca4 0x3efa000 + 15524
4   dyld                            0x03f00588 0x3efa000 + 25992
5   dyld                            0x03efb1d0 0x3efa000 + 4560
6   dyld                            0x03efb040 0x3efa000 + 4160

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x04064228
    r4: 0x000000ab    r5: 0x04063e28      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x04063df4
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x000000ab     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000209    sp: 0x04063db4      lr: 0x03f1be3f      pc: 0x03f1c1dc
  cpsr: 0x40000010

Binary Images:
0x98000 - 0x3af3fff CPEEP.iOS armv7  <8d939558dc293773ba5dbe06524a29ef> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/23B56006-7F53-468B-AAC2-18B74EA02613/CPEEP.iOS.app/CPEEP.iOS
0x3efa000 - 0x3f25fff dyld armv7s  <f0f6706c72713272afd9a5f6ec9b6071> /usr/lib/dyld
0x4066000 - 0x4439fff libSkiaSharp armv7  <3d824f59dc7b393c906a666eaa541d0e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/23B56006-7F53-468B-AAC2-18B74EA02613/CPEEP.iOS.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp

EOF
```

Here is my build config:
[I build for ARMv7 + ARM64, with my configuration set to AppStore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFBpo.png)

I've looked around but most solutions to problems of this nature seem to deal with Swift or XCode and not Xamarin/Visual Studio.

I have tried this solution : https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/xamarin/XamarinComponents/597/520597929 with no success.

I am a beginner when it comes to Xamarin and deploying apps.

Edit:

So it turns out the Frameworks in my .ipa have a info.plist files with a *UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities* key with the value *arm64* which makes Apple's thinning process remove armv7 versions of these frameworks. I have no clue why this key appears in those frameworks however.

Affected frameworks :

- MaterialComponents.framework
- MDFInternationalization.framework
- MDFTextAccessibility.framework
- MotionAnimator.framework
- MotionInterchange.framework
- MotionTransitioning.framework

Unaffected frameworks :

- libSkiaSharp.framework

Comment: what is your linker set to when building for the app store? the error says the MaterialComponents.framework library isn't loaded. The linker can sometimes remove things it thinks aren't being used. Are the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 running the same version of iOS?

Comment: It is set to : "Link Framework SDKs only". I am currently publishing a version to test with the linker set to "Don't link". 

The iPhone5 is on iOs 10.3.4 whereas the iPhone6s+ is on 12.4.

Comment: my guess is it's a linker issue, but it could also be that framework doesn't support that version of iOS.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I am still stuck at the place where I was when I added the Edit, not knowing how to ensure that the frameworks generated by Xamarin/Visual Studio while archiving have an Info.Plist that does not specify a UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities of arm64. I haven't been able to spend a lot of time on this issue though.